# Using Azure Rest API with Postman to Update Logic App Recurrence Frequency

Tags: azure, postman, azure-logic-apps

We have a logic app which polls the service bus every 30 minutes for messages.  I'd like to use Postman to update the polling frequency to 30 seconds for testing.

I can use the Azure API to get details of the Workflow associated with the logic app and then get the trigger in that Workflow associated with polling the service bus.  This returns JSON like:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "createdTime": "2019-08-13T21:08:14.8768439Z",
        "changedTime": "2019-10-21T14:32:46.0204187Z",
        "state": "Enabled",
        "status": "Running",
        "lastExecutionTime": "2019-10-21T14:32:04.149971Z",
        "nextExecutionTime": "2019-10-21T14:32:46.285845Z",
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Second",
            "interval": 30
        },
        "workflow": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/<workflow-name>/versions/08586299385548076458",
            "name": "08586299385548076458",
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/versions"
        }
    },
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/<workflow-name>/triggers/When_a_message_is_received_in_a_topic_subscription_(auto-complete)",
    "name": "When_a_message_is_received_in_a_topic_subscription_(auto-complete)",
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers"
}
```

In the above structure, I want to PATCH `"recurrence" : { "frequency": "Second" }` to `"recurrence" : { "frequency": "Minute" }`

From looking at the [REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/logic/workflowtriggers/setstate) it is unclear to me if this is possible?  I see the Trigger has a setState option and one of the properties is RecurrenceFrequency but if I try and use this I get the following error returned:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "WorkflowTriggerSetStateNotSupported",
        "message": "The workflow trigger 'When_a_message_is_received_in_a_topic_subscription_(auto-complete)' of type 'ApiConnection' does not support the set state action."
    }
}
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can tell me if this is possible, what I am doing wrong or point me to an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer & Workaround

Unfortunately, despite the API documentation suggesting it's possible, you cannot use setState to update a trigger of any type, native or managed, enabled or not.

- Native response:

`{"error":{"code":"WorkflowTriggerSetStateNotSupported","message":"The workflow trigger 'Recurrence' of type 'Recurrence' does not support the set state action."}}`

- Managed response:

`{"error":{"code":"WorkflowTriggerSetStateNotSupported","message":"The workflow trigger 'sbAuto' of type 'ApiConnection' does not support the set state action."}}`

Neither can you use the PATCH verb to update a workflow:

`{"error":{"code":"PatchWorkflowPropertiesNotSupported","message":"The request to patch workflow 'XXXXXXX' is not supported. None of the fields inside the properties object can be patched."}}`

I've raised this issue with Microsoft.

### However...

What *is* possible is using the PUT verb to update the workflow.

In order to achieve this, it is best to retrieve the workflow using the GET verb, update the JSON recurrence object, and reissue using a PUT (Create or Update).

My example below gets the definition of a workflow I created *tempotestla*.

Request:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/651a2541-8d19-42a0-85fe-89a9eee81c48/resourceGroups/TechSouth/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/tempotestla?api-version=2016-06-01 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: management.azure.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Length: 0
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1431
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
x-ms-request-id: uksouth:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-resource-requests: 19999
x-ms-correlation-request-id: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
x-ms-routing-request-id: UKSOUTH2:20191022T160012Z:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 16:00:11 GMT

{
    "properties":{
        "provisioningState":"Succeeded",
        "createdTime":"2019-10-22T13:27:18.8425031Z",
        "changedTime":"2019-10-22T15:59:39.3684114Z",
        "state":"Disabled",
        "version":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "accessEndpoint":"https://prod-00.uksouth.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "definition":{
            "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
            "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
            "parameters":{

            },
            "triggers":{
                "Recurrence":{
                    "recurrence":{
                        "frequency":"Hour",
                        "interval":5
                    },
                    "type":"Recurrence"
                }
            },
            "actions":{
                "Terminate":{
                    "runAfter":{

                    },
                    "type":"Terminate",
                    "inputs":{
                        "runStatus":"Succeeded"
                    }
                }
            },
            "outputs":{

            }
        },
        "parameters":{

        },
        "endpointsConfiguration":{
            "workflow":{
                "outgoingIpAddresses":[
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.74.14"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.73.85"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.78.44"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.137.190"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.153.135"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.28.225"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.142.28"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.158.24"
                    }
                ],
                "accessEndpointIpAddresses":[
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.79.109"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.78.71"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.84.39"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.155.81"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "connector":{
                "outgoingIpAddresses":[
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.80.51"
                    },
                    {
                        "address":"51.140.148.0/28"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "id":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/tempotestla",
    "name":"tempotestla",
    "type":"Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
    "location":"uksouth",
    "tags":{

    }
}
```

This is my workflow overview page:

---

[image: Workflow Overview - 5 Hour Trigger]

---

From here, if you're using object oriented code or script, you can deserialize the response body and change the interval:

```
objResponse.properties.definition.triggers.<TriggerType>.<TriggerName>.frequency = "Minute"
```

Then, reserialize your object and send it back to the API in a PUT request.  Here I'm changing hours to days:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/tempotestla?api-version=2016-06-01 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: management.azure.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Length: 1534

{
    "properties":{
        "provisioningState":"Succeeded",
        "createdTime":"2019-10-22T15:25:16.1635472Z",
        "changedTime":"2019-10-22T15:25:16.153712Z",
        "state":"Disabled",
        "version":"08586298489693318400",
        "accessEndpoint":"https://prod-00.uksouth.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "definition":{
            "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
            "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
            "parameters":{

            },
            "triggers":{
                "Recurrence":{
                    "recurrence":{
                        "frequency":"Day",
                        "interval":5
                    },
                    "type":"Recurrence"
                }
            },
            "actions":{
                "Terminate":{
                    "runAfter":{

                    },
                    "type":"Terminate",
                    "inputs":{
                        "runStatus":"Succeeded"
                    }
                }
            },
            "outputs":{

            }
        },
        "parameters":{

        },
    },
    "id":"/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/tempotestla",
    "name":"tempotestla",
    "type":"Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
    "location":"uksouth",
    "tags":{

    }
}
```

You should get an updated object back in the response body.

Here's my workflow summary page after issuing the request:

---

[image: 5 Day Trigger]

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for the response.  The trigger is a service bus trigger - is there some documentation you can point me to that shows it is not capable of using SetState?  I tried updating the trigger using the format you suggested but I still get the same response " 'ApiConnection' does not support the set state action"  - I am using https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{SubscriptionID}}/resourcegroups/{{OffResGroup}}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{{CmtLAName}}/triggers/{{TriggerName}}/setState?api-version=2016-06-01 to attempt this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Steve please see my update.  Hope this gives you a viable solution :)

Comment: Jamie, thanks very much for this it looks like it will work (I just need more granular permissions than Logic App Contributor as the Workflow has to update a bunch of resources).  I'll mark as answered as soon as I can verify. Cheers!

Comment: No problem.  You could create a custom role definition with action `"Microsoft.Logic/workflows/write"` assignable scope `"/subscriptions/{{SubscriptionID}}/resourceGroups/{{OffResGroup}}/{{CmtLAName}}"`